# Environment null is coming after executing this method

Tags: android, adb

```
public static String[] getAdbLogCat() {
    try {
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:/androidsoftware/android sdk/platform-tools/adb shell logcat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            Log.e("ADB TEST",line);
        }

        return (String[])arrList.toArray(new String[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new String[]{};
    }
}
```

Environment null is coming after executing this method.I am running this in emulator.What if i want to run in mobile then what will be the adb path? My requirement is to read the adb log and save the crash data into a table.My android sdk located in d drive.Or is there any other way to get my application crash log from android system log.

[image: log cat error]

Answer (score 0):

You can't run executable programs on your computer from within an app running on an emulator.  You can only run programs that live in the emulator's own space.  The emulator is like an actual device, and you would never expect a device to reach outside itself to execute some other process.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bridge to contact the host-environment from your android application.

Sample project: https://github.com/toantran-ea/adb-ci-bridge

You can extend the function with new endpoint in that library. And make call to from your application.

Sample request with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"tag":"sample tag value","trace":"TooAwesomeException foo bar"}' http://localhost:9001/screenshot
```

This is used in some limited contexts, like when you running on a Continuous Sever and you need some utility functions to contact with host (for screenshot, reporting, or something else).